# Overload Resolution in C# 4.0 using dynamic types

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic-language-runtime, dynamic-languages, overloading

I don't have access to the C# 4.0 preview yet. But I am curious, what does the C# 4.0 runtime do when invoking an overloaded method in the following case. Does it resolve to the generic overload ... or the specialized overload.

```
public class Foo<T>
{
  protected string BarImpl( T value ) { return "Bar(T) says: " + value.ToString(); }

  protected string BarImpl( int value ) { return "Bar(int) says: " + value.ToString(); }

  public string Bar( T value )
  {
    dynamic foo = this;
    return foo.BarImpl( value );
  }
}

public static void Main( string args[] )
{
  var f = new Foo<int>();

  Console.WriteLine( f.Bar( 0 ) );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, my understanding that the result should (whenever possible) be the same as the result would be if you compiled the same code with *just* the dynamic expressions replaced by expressions of the type that the dynamic value has at execution time. (Statically-known types are preserved in the call site info.)

In this particular case, having just your code with .NET 4.0b1, the result is:

```
Bar(int) says: 0
```

However, having looked at this again (and checked which bit is actually dynamic) I'm slightly confused. I think it's one of those situations where I'd have to look *very* carefully at the spec to understand what the correct behaviour is. Unfortunately I don't know when the C# 4.0 spec will be available.

It's a tricky one to reason about, and I suspect the key part is whether at execution time the binder is able to work out that the value is of type `T` for the same `T` as the receiver, rather than type `int`. Because the *receiver* is dynamic in this case, the compiler doesn't do any overload resolution at all. Hmm. Tricky one, definitely.

Comment: I've read the series ... there wasn't a clear case analogous to my example, so I can't be certain. The impression I get from what I've read is that Bar( int ) will get called. Which would be very nice, because it would make it possible for me to use dynamic as a way to implement C# generic type specialization ... something that up until now hasn't been very easy (or elegant) to do.

Comment: Yup, Bar(int) is called. I've edited my answer because I'd slightly misread your question. And yes, it's handy to use dynamic to do all kinds of things like this. I like the case where you know something is a Foo<T> really, but you don't know what T is, so you can't call any generic methods...

Comment: I hadn't thought of this sort of specialization before though... very interesting. I wonder how efficient it'll turn out to be. I've seen pretty good performance from the DLR so far.

Comment: This behavior is different from C# 3.5 without the dynamic keyword. Calling foo.Bar(0) returns "Bar(T) says 0" in that case.

Comment: I've recently implemented a version of generic type specialization that uses Linq.Expression to build dynamic delegates for .NET 3.5 - it works, I'm just trying to optimize the performance before I post an article online about the technique. My hope is that with C# 4.0 - dynamic will be a better and more performance way to achieve the same results.

Comment: @LBushkin:foo.Bar(0) returns "Bar(T) says 0" because the compile-time type of "value" is T. If you change the compile-time type to int, it will return "Bar(int) says 0". That's what I meant by the bit of my answer where I talk about dynamic expressions being replaced by values of the type that the dynamic value has at execution time.

Comment: (Having said which, I think the final bit of my answer is incorrect... I'll edit.)

Comment: Yup, I get how the compiler resolves the overloads - I just think it's interesting that the DLR resolves the calls differently. I suspect that can introduce unexpected behavioral differences in an application - just by switching from using strong typing to dynamic typing. Not something that most people would expect - and a tricky thing to debug I imagine. However, this behavior can also be useful in certain contexts - such as for my idea to use it for generic type specialization.

Comment: Just don't forget that it could still change before C# 4 finally ships. Unfortunately I could really do with understanding it better than I do, in order to write about it sensibly.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: @John: Thanks, I've removed the paragraph as it looks like the blog posts are basically gone.